# How can I remove the year from Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this bootstrap date picker: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/v1.9.0/index.html

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="datepicker" data-date="12/03/2012"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
```

**JS Code:**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format : 'MM'
});

$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
    $('#my_hidden_input').val(
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
    );
});
```

Now, it's showing Month with year. For example: February 2020

How can I remove the year?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `options`, specifically `format`?

Comment: I used `$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   format : 'MM'
  });` but not working

Comment: If you don't want a day or year (i.e. only month), why don't you just use a `select` field with the months of the year as `option`s?

Comment: I need to show the calendar Inline Format with the year.

Comment: Sorry with out the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Do like This:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'L',
  dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMMM'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```